# PANDAS: How to access keys of groupby object when attempting to apply multiple functions

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {"index":{"0":1692,"1":1771,"2":1007,"3":2915,"4":1416},
"item_number":{"0":"123","1":"123","2":"124","3":"124","4":"125"},
"brand":{"0":"brand1","1":"brand1","2":"brand2","3":"brand2","4":"brand3"},
"price":{"0":20.00,"1":20.00,"2":25.00,"3":25.00,"4":30.00},
"comp_id":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":1,"3":3,"4":2},
"comp":{"0":"comp1","1":"comp2","2":"comp1","3":"comp3","4":"comp2"},
"comp_price":{"0":21.00,"1":20.99,"2":16.00,"3":15.99,"4":29.99}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

g = df1.groupby('brand')
v = df1[df1['price']>df1['comp_price']].groupby('brand')

#number of skus within each brand
brand_sku_count = g.apply(lambda x: len(x['item_number'].unique()))

#number of skus violated within each brand
brand_vio_count = v.apply(lambda x: len(x['item_number'].unique()))

#number of sellers within each brand
total_sellers = g.apply(lambda x: len(x['comp_id'].unique()))

#number of violators within each brand
total_violators = v.apply(lambda x: len(x['comp_id'].unique()))

brand_report = pd.concat([brand_sku_count, brand_vio_count, 
total_sellers, total_violators], axis=1)
brand_report.columns = ['sku_count','vio_count','total_comps','total_vios']
```

The above is my old code, I recently discovered transform and the agg function. I'm trying to learn how to cut down on doing these functions one at a time and then piecing them all back together using concat. I feel there's an opportunity to greatly reduce the amount of lines of code here.

I've read the questions where you can do the following:

```
df1.groupby('brand')['item_number'].agg(['sum','count'])
```

I've tried doing:

```
f1 = lambda x: len(x['item_number'].unique())
f2 = lambda x: len(x['comp_id'].unique())
f = {'item_number':f1, 'comp_id':f2}
df1.groupby('brand').agg(f)
```

This returns:

```
KeyError: 'item_number'
```

So I tried:

```
f1 = lambda x: len(x.get_group('item_number').unique())
f2 = lambda x: len(x.get_group('comp_id').unique())
f = {'item_number':f1, 'comp_id':f2}
df1.groupby('brand').agg(f)
```

This returned an error saying a Series object does not have get_group

Comment: have you tried a pivot_table? `df1Pivot = df1.pivot_table(index = 'brand',aggfunc = lambda x: len(x.unique()))` Something along those lines?

Comment: i'm reading through http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
f1 = lambda x: len(x.unique())
f = {'item_number':f1, 'comp_id':f1}
df1.groupby('brand').agg(f)

Out[881]: 
        item_number  comp_id
brand                       
brand1            1        2
brand2            1        2
brand3            1        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables will also work:

```
lst= ['brand', 'comp_id','item_number']

df1Pivot = df1[lst].pivot_table(index = 'brand',aggfunc = lambda x: len(x.unique()))
df1Pivot.rename(columns ={'item_number':'sku_count','comp_id':'total_comps'}, inplace = True)


df2Pivot  = df1[df1['price']>df1['comp_price']][lst].pivot_table(index = 'brand',aggfunc = lambda x: len(x.unique()))
df2Pivot.rename(columns ={'item_number':'vio_count','comp_id':'total_vios'}, inplace = True)


df3 = df1Pivot.join(df2Pivot)
```